# Safari 11 - blocks multiple pop ups

Tags: mac, safari, software-update

I am using a button on my site that opens multiple pop-up windows in one click.

Since the update of September 20, 2017 - it doesn't work and only one window pops up at a time.

On my other Mac - which has the Safari 10.1 version - it works.

Tried to find answers on Mac rumors and other sites with no success.

I have two questions :

- Is it possible to open multiple pop-up windows on Safari 11? If so, how?
- How do I restore to Safari 10? I searched the web for answers but couldn't find any.

Anyone has an answer for me or could guide me to the right place?

Comment: Well in this case I have two questions : 1) Is it possible to open multiple pop up windows on safari 11? if so, how? 2) How do I restore to safari 10. I searched the web for answers but couldn't find any.

Comment: What's the question here? You either have to re-code your page's (JavaScript) code to comply to Safari 11 pop-up window policies or restore Safari 10. The first possible question/answer is better suited at stackexchange.com and the second (changing Safari 11 behavior is just beyond our reach - except you modify some windows pop-up prefs in Safari 11, if possible at all) would be a Time Machine backup.

Comment: It would be a better choice to recode your site - multiple pop-ups on a single click is a not good UI design and prone to nefarious uses (which is probably why Safari 11 doesn't support it)

Comment: I'm using it on my company web system console. It's for inside use and it is required by us to open 5 windows at a time.

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46381681/open-multiple-pop-up-windows-in-safari-11)  Whether it's internal or external, multiple pop-ups are discouraged.  To get this to work, you will have to disable pop-up blocker on Safari and this is not a good workaround.